# How to make flex item the same height as parent (with auto-height, by text) while keeping aspect ratio working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

Look at this: https://codepen.io/xsjctony/pen/KKrQoBY

```css
body {
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
}

.copy-text {
  display: inline-flex;
  column-gap: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.copy-text button {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='none' height='20' width='20' stroke='rgba(128,128,128,1)' stroke-width='2' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' d='M9 5H7a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V7a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-2M9 5a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2M9 5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: border-color 0.25s;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.copy-text button:hover {
  border-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="copy-text">
  <span>/api</span>
  <button title="Copy Text" type="button" class="copy"></button>
</div>
```

I have a button after the text [image], but unfortunately currently the button does not have width (2px is because of border). `aspect-ratio` seems not working.

Requirement:

1. button's width must be the same as its dynamic height (i.e. a PERFECT SQUARE)
2. Can wrap elements around `<button>`, but try not to edit other HTML structure
3. the container must be `inline` or `inline-*` display
4. button's height must follow the parent's height, which is the same as text's `line-height` (unknown value, as this maybe used in multiple different places)

This is what I want ideally (done by fixed width and height, but that's not what I want)
[image]

Comment: First of all, you please look at this: [mre] - it belongs _directly_ into your question, please do not just send us to some external platform.

Answer (score 1):

I tried solving your ask. The best possible way we can do that is using flexbox. I added display flex to the container, provided flex-basis to both the child elements and removed the aspect ratio. Please refer to the below code snippet:-

HTML

```
<div class="copy-text">
  <span>/api</span>
  <button title="Copy Text" type="button" class="copy"></button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
}

.copy-text {
  display:flex; /* Added this */
  column-gap: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.copy-text span {
 flex-basis: 20px; /* Added here */
}

.copy-text button {
  flex-basis:20px; /* Added here and removed the aspect ratio */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='none' height='20' width='20' stroke='rgba(128,128,128,1)' stroke-width='2' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' d='M9 5H7a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V7a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-2M9 5a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2M9 5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: border-color 0.25s;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.copy-text button:hover {
  border-color: #666;
}
```

Here is the JS Fiddle link for reference:-

https://jsfiddle.net/jytpqL3c/

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but it does not meet my requirement as I need the button to be a perfect square :(

Answer (score 0):

> which is the same as text's line-height

So use the `line-height` value to set the size

```css
body {
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
}

.copy-text {
  display: inline-flex;
  column-gap: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.2em; /* here */
}

.copy-text button {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: inherit; /* don't forget this to use the same font-size */
  height: 1.2em; /* and here */
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='none' height='20' width='20' stroke='rgba(128,128,128,1)' stroke-width='2' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' d='M9 5H7a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V7a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-2M9 5a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2M9 5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: border-color 0.25s;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.copy-text button:hover {
  border-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="copy-text">
  <span>/api</span>
  <button title="Copy Text" type="button" class="copy"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I don't know the line-height here? it's a component and going to be re-used on other places, and the line-height is also dynamic